# Ruby what's the lazy way to get input in loop

Tags: ruby, console

Say I want to get 10 inputs in loop and store it in an array. The input will be either string or line or json string.

I'm aware of Ruby's `upto` and `gets.chomp` but I'm looking for a simple and lazy technique like:

```
n=10
arr = []
loop(n) { arr.push getline }  #Just an example to share my thought. Will not work
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't know if this is "simple and lazy" enough:

```
irb> 3.times.collect { gets.chomp }
foo
bar
baz
# => ["foo", "bar", baz"]
```

Comment: That's a neat trick. I would have done `[*0...3].map { gets.chomp }` but that's much cleaner

Answer (score 4):

`Array.new`.

```
Array.new(3){gets.chomp}
```

Comment: @toro2k Interesting.  In Pry the first time, it did only return [3].  after shutting it down, and checking IRB, I got the expected behavior, and then Pry also behaves the same.  Wonder what the difference was.

Comment: Works with 1.8 and up, haven't tried anything less than 1.8.7.

Answer (score 0):

```
(1..3).map {gets.strip!}
```

This works nice, and is clean for noise before and after the entries.

Valid in 1.9 and 2.0.

```
>> (1..3).map {gets.strip!}
Hello
1
2
=> ["Hello", "1", "2"]
```

Comment: You seem to be implying that some other answer (particularly mine) does not work with 2.0. But, are you sure?

Comment: :) I was surprised when yours did not work in my Pry session.  Been working with Pry on a TK editor though, so obviously had something contaminated.  You know, @sawa I am always learning something from you.